mybatis config typealiases suddenly not worked
It worked before but when I moved the root directory, There's suddenly occured config xml parsing exception while Executing Spring Boot App
Why does the exceptions are occur?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0/EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">


<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="callSettersOnNulls" value="false"/>
    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.example..drawing.dto"/>
    </typeAliases>

    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="com.example.utils.MyBatisTypeHandler" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
    </typeHandlers>
</configuration>

Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: URL [classpath:mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 177, end 116, length 116
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:589) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:490) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:632) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration.sqlSessionFactory(MybatisAutoConfiguration.java:180) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$367ea3da.CGLIB$sqlSessionFactory$2(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$367ea3da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cee5a4e.invoke(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$367ea3da.sqlSessionFactory(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 177, end 116, length 116
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:99) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:586) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 177, end 116, length 116
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4608) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2711) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2684) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.preserveSubpackageName(SpringBootVFS.java:62) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.lambda$list$0(SpringBootVFS.java:54) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.list(SpringBootVFS.java:55) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.VFS.list(VFS.java:223) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ResolverUtil.find(ResolverUtil.java:250) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:125) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.typeAliasesElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:165) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:110) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    ... 74 common frames omitted

If I remove those typeAliases and write full Object Ref in Sql Mapper xml, It is operate in normal
enter image description here
  <select id="getShipNoList" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="String" resultType="com.example.drawing.dto.ShipNoResDto">
        SELECT
            SHIP_NO
        FROM PTB_SHIP_BASIC
        WHERE DLY_YN = #{DLY_YN}
    </select>


The package name com.example..drawing.dto looks invalid. There should be no consecutive dots ...
